# How evaluate text clustering?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, text-mining

What metrics can be used for evaluating text clustering models? I used `tf-idf` + `k-means`, `tf-idf` + `hierarchical clustering`, `doc2vec` + `k-means (metric is cosine similarity)`, `doc2vec` + `hierarchical clustering (metric is cosine similarity)`. 
How to decide which model is the best?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out [this paper](https://www.stat.washington.edu/raftery/Research/PDF/fraley1998.pdf).  It also addresses question of how many clusters to use.  The R package [mclust](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mclust/index.html) has a routine which will try different cluster models/number of clusters and plot the Bayesian inference criterion (BIC). (great vignette [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mclust/vignettes/mclust.html)).  It's a general method, meaning, something you can do without being domain/data specific.  (It's always good to be domain-specific if you have the time and data.)

The chart is from the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mclust/vignettes/mclust.html) by Lucca Scrucca.  MClust tries 14 different clustering algorithms (represented by the different symbols), increasing the number of clusters from 1 to some default value.  It's finds the BIC each time.  Highest BIC is usually the best choice.  You could apply this methodology to your own stable of clustering algorithms.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check out [silhouette score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_kmeans_silhouette_analysis.html)

**Formula for *i* th data point**

```
(b(i) - a(i)) / max(a(i),b(i))
```

where **b(i)** -> dissimilarity from nearest neighbouring cluster

**a(i)** -> dissimilarity between points within cluster

This gives a score between -1 and +1.

**Interpretation**

+1 means very good fit

-1 means misclassified [should have belonged to a  different cluster]

After calculating silhouette score for each data point, you can take a call on the choice for the number of clusters.

**Code Example**

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_samples, silhouette_score

X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=500,
                  n_features=2,
                  centers=4,
                  cluster_std=1,
                  center_box=(-10.0, 10.0),
                  shuffle=True,
                  random_state=1)  # For reproducibility

range_n_clusters = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

for n_clusters in range_n_clusters:
    # Initialize the clusterer with n_clusters value and a random generator
    # seed of 10 for reproducibility.
    clusterer = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters, random_state=10)
    cluster_labels = clusterer.fit_predict(X)

    # The silhouette_score gives the average value for all the samples.
    # This gives a perspective into the density and separation of the formed
    # clusters
    silhouette_avg = silhouette_score(X, cluster_labels)
    print("For n_clusters =", n_clusters,
          "The average silhouette_score is :", silhouette_avg)

    # Compute the silhouette scores for each sample
    sample_silhouette_values = silhouette_samples(X, cluster_labels)
```

Answer (score 0):

A clustering quality measure would be very nice to have. Unfortunately, that measure is hard to calculate -- probably AI-hard. You are trying to reduce a very complex thing to a single number.

If it is AI-hard, then you could ask people to rate the clusterings somehow. It's not ideal, and won't scale but you will have a  single number that represents something close to what you want.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. I can simply feed a well-studied text document into the models. Then compare the cluster membership with my expectation.

Comment: Yep. Using "your" expectation is what you do when the measure is AI-hard. You would get a better measure if you include other people's expectations.

Comment: I have an idea. I can try to train classificator and fit it with labels from different models with same number of clusters. The better accurancy_score, the better model.

Answer (score 0):

Though `silhouette_score` is a good parameter to evaluate model performance, you can also use `davies_bouldin_score`. The *Davies-Bouldin Score (DBS)* can be imported from `sklearn.metrics` using [sklearn](/questions/tagged/sklearn) library.

Here the minimum score is 0, but the maximum score can be above 1.

I would recommend saving the model-predicted output in [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) and evaluating it manually to realize how the model predictions are coming.

Use:

```py
from sklearn.metrics import davies_bouldin_score
dbs = davies_bouldin_score(feature_12.toarray(), model. Labels_)
```